# Why does scripting in Scala recommends /bin/sh?

Tags: scala, scripting, shebang

I'm reading the [Script it!](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html#script-it) section of [Getting Started with Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html). It includes the following example:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
HelloWorld.main(args)
```

My question is: why `#!/bin/sh` + `exec`? Can't we just use `#!/usr/bin/env scala` as the shebang?

That's what we do with many other languages: Perl, Python, Node, ... What's wrong with it?

**UPDATE:** This question is not about whether `#!/usr/bin/env scala` works or not. It works, if you don't believe it for whatever reason, try it. This question is about why the `#!/bin/sh` way is recommended/documented, and the other is not. After all, `#!/usr/bin/env <something>` is the de-facto standard for all other languages.

Do I lose some functionality by using `#!/usr/bin/env scala`? (Except the ability of running arbitrary shell script before launching Scala, of course.)

Comment: Cause no one thought of `scalabang` wrapper to do this, I guess.

Comment: @TNW: `#!/usr/bin/env scala` **works**. Try it, you'll see

Comment: So it's as wrong as other shebangs, ie. it isn't.